# Meteor DB not showing up in Genghisapp?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is on a brand new install of Meteor. I'm using Meteor 1.4 and my GenghisApp:

'genghisapp' 2.3.11

rack 1.3

sinatra 1.4.6

vegas 0.1.11

Everything else is default.

I add `localhost:3001` to the GenghisApp web terminal and while it sees that there is a Meteor db, it's empty. The collections don't even show up. But I can confirm in Meteor Shell that there are documents in there.

I've used GenghisApp before on all my past Meteor projects and it's always worked fine.

Comment: What version of the Ruby driver is your GenghisApp using? Meteor 1.4 includes MongoDB 3.2 which defaults to the WiredTiger storage engine; older tools/drivers need an update for full compatibility. Without an update, typical symptoms of an outdated driver are not being able to list collections with the WiredTiger storage engine and not being able to authenticate in MongoDB 3.0+. For Ruby, you should have the 2.2 driver or newer: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/driver-compatibility/.

Comment: How do I check which version Genghisapp is using? When I do `gem install mongo` the versions I get are `bson-4.1.1
and mongo-2.2.7`

Comment: Oh, wait, I see. It seems to be a new issue with Genghisapp. Seems like I need to wait for an update to Genghisapp. Are there any alternatives for a browser-based MongoDB GUI you can recommend that will work with WiredTiger?